# T-SQL cursor loop syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

Just a simple style question I've always been curious about.

The canonical forward only cursor loop goes like this.

```
DECLARE table_data FORWARD_ONLY CURSOR FOR
SELECT c1, c2
FROM t1;

DECLARE @c1 int;
DECLARE @c2 int;

OPEN table_data;
FETCH table_data INTO @c1, @c2;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    -- do something with @c1, @c2
    FETCH table_data INTO @c1, @c2;
END;

CLOSE table_data;
DEALLOCATE table_data;
```

There's a minor code style issue in that the FETCH statement is repeated verbatim. Is there any reason that this is the "standard" loop when it could just as easily be written like this?

```
OPEN table_data;
WHILE 1 = 1
    FETCH table_data INTO @c1, @c2;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS != 0 BREAK;
    -- do something with @c1, @c2
END;
```

I'm not really looking for opinions on which way is better. I'm just curious if there's a reason that the first way seems to be overwhelmingly the standard which it can be argued to have this drawback. Is there a problem with the infinite loop version that I'm not seeing?

I'm guessing the reason is that BREAK is a recent T-SQL addition, but I'm having trouble finding a changelog of the T-SQL language to confirm this hypothesis.

Comment: A better question when you see a cursor is "how can I turn this into a set based solution and get rid of this cursor entirely".

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that, I'm just curious why the loops are typically written in this weird way.

Comment: To answer your question, I for one do not like loops in any language that use while 1 = 1. It is easy to end up in an endless loop when you are counting on something inside to always control the loop.

Comment: The second code block as entered will loop infinitely.  You're missing your BEGIN.